# An Error occurred while local report processing

Tags: c#, sqlite, visual-studio-2013, reportviewer

Here's the Error Details:

[image: Here's the Error Details]

This is the first time have developed Windows Form Application using C# (using Visual studio 2013 , Sq-lite Database , Microsoft Report Viewer 10.0, Windows 10). It works perfectly fine on Windows 10 but gives an error while using the application on Windows 7 on printing the report as "An Error occurred while local report processing".

Here is the error screen:

[image: ![enter image description here]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CalpQ.png)

Comment: The error description that would appear if one would click on 'Details' would be nice to know.

Comment: Is this all the details section tells you? I was hoping for the type of the exception, the error message and a stacktrace.

Comment: Yes , it is the details section displayed on clients Machine.

Comment: Well then it is nearly impossible to help you with that. It just tells us what we already know from your explanation (the used assemblies). Without the exceptions message (or the exception type like NullReferenceException) and the stacktrace one could only guess. The chances of getting an answer would improve if you'd manage to get those details (by debugging it with VS).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the Microsoft Report Viewer 2010 Redistributable Packages and Add '**Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel.dll**'  in  setup.you might be missing some dll